# What to do about people posting copyrighted material?

Tags: discussion

So, I've recently come across [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14707/how-can-i-layer-my-textures-in-blender) and I noticed that the first image comes from [Carlos Ortega's website](http://carlosortega.prosite.com/150824/2766963/portfolio/stamens-of-light) and is Copyrighted; What should I do?

Answer (score 5):

Quoting from http://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy

> Copyright. Using copyrighted material does not constitute infringement in all cases. In general, however, users should be careful when using copyrighted content without the permission of those who created it. It is our policy to respond to notices of alleged infringement that comply with the Digital Millennium Copyright Act ("DMCA").

I would say that the question named if it had a link to the source would not a problem. But to be on the safe side, adding just a link to the picture, and not posting the picture would not violate any copyright.

Comment: So, just let it be?

Comment: @someonewithpc that question is closed now, so do not worry about that particular instance.